# Dynamically show text field's contents on labels

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to enter names using input field and then show those names dynamically on the click of a button. Can anyone provide me with a code sample that does that?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place where you just ask for code... What have you already tried? We are here to help not to write your code.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is fairly easy to do with jquery. However while asking a question first give it a try and then ask if you dont get it.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#submit').on('click', function(){
      var value = $('#name').val();
      var text = '<p>' + value + '</p>';
      $('#display').append(text);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="inputNames" id="name">
<button id="submit">Submit</button>

<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<body>
<input type="text" name="Names" id="Names">
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="SendName();" name="">

<p id="ShowNames"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SendName() {
        var d= document;
        var InputNames = d.getElementById("Names").value;
        var ShowNames = d.getElementById("ShowNames");
        ShowNames.innerHTML +=InputNames+"</br>";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```